# Error in st_intersects() %>% as.numeric() : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: st-intersects

I'm working with 2 shapefiles (sf) containing longitude and latitude for both schools locations (shape_schools) and parks locations (shape_parks). I also have a shapefile containing mutually exclusive polygons (shape_upz). I would like to find the index of the polygon where each point is contained.

The code works when working with the sf of schools but it does not with the parks sf. Schools sf has 2572 observations and polygon sf has 113 observations. Format of polygons sf is "sfc_GEOMETRY" "sfc" and formats of both schools and parks sf are  "sfc_POINT" "sfc".

The code works for schools sf and the polygon sf. Code is as follows:

index_of_intersection <- st_intersects(shape_schools, shape_upz, sparse = T) %>%
as.numeric()

As I said the last code works but the following with the parks sf does not:

index_of_intersection_parks <- st_intersects(shape_parks, shape_upz, sparse = T) %>%
as.numeric()

Parks sf has 5252 observations. The error with the code when working with parks sf is the following:

Error in st_intersects(shape_parks, shape_upz, sparse = T) %>% as.numeric() :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

How could I solve that problem without splitting the data or do you think the problem is caused for other kind reason? Hope you can help.